# How to read db properties file for different environments in camel and jenkins

Tags: spring, apache, jenkins, apache-camel

Hi I want read properties for dev,prod environments , Is this any way do this?
I'm doing like below ,but no use

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"  destroy-
method="close" id="dataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver.class}"/>
<property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
<property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}"/>
<property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
<property name="maxIdle" value="20"/>
<property name="maxActive" value="20"/>
</bean>

  <bean
    class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" 
id="bridgePropertyPlaceholder">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:db-${envTarget}.properties"/>
</bean>
```

I'm doing like this and giving my goal as

```
    clean install -DenvTarget=dev
```

but not working, please help me here .

Answer (score 0):

Use [Spring profiles and environment abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.14.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-environment) for this.

Then you can simply use different property files like `db-[profilename].properties` and they are automatically loaded according to the active profiles.